# How to use the system kernel binary itself as dump-capture kernel?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I want to set up kdump without building separate crash kernel.
How to use the system kernel binary itself as dump-capture kernel?

Comment: Just use system kernel instead crash kernel, what is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you need to install kexec-tools and kdump, although you may not require to recompile the kernel (depending on which flavour being used), you would still require to reboot the box to get the kdump settings in effect after configuring kdump. kdump is essentially a reliable version of the kernel has the crash dumping mechanism that utilizes the kexec software. Kexec is a fast boot mechanism that allows booting a Linux kernel without going through the BIOS again.

Now if you are not going to have another reliable kernel, what is the guarantee that your kernel code in-core is not corrupted and would work correctly, when you have memory corruption, panic, hung-state or possibly in an unreliable state. Therefore its not longer secure to rely on your running kernel for getting the dump.

Hope this helps.